# Light and Dark mode based on system setting and button click in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code on my website where I am trying to set light or dark mode based on the settings of the users system/browser as well as the ability to change the setting based on a button press.

What I want to happen is:

1. It is daytime orthe users browser is set to light. The website loads the light.css and the button shows the moon icon to switch to the light theme.
2. It is night time or the user has their theme set to dark mode. The website loads the dark.css theme and the icon in the button switches to the sun.

Perhaps I am missing something here to get it all functioning correctly? Mainly the buttons do not switch.

```js
function lightDark() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll(".light, .dark")
  if (el.href.match("light.css")) {
    el.href = "dark.css";
  } else {
    el.href = "light.css";
  }
}

<
script type = "text/javascript" >
  $('#lightDarkToggle').click(function() {
      if (window.matchMedia('prefers-color-scheme: dark').matches) {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-sun'),
          el.href = "dark.css";

      } else {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-moon'),
          el.href = "light.css";
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link class="light" rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference), (prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
<link class="dark" rel="stylesheet" href="dark.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />

<button id="lightDarkToggle" onclick="lightDark()"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></button>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a nodeList, but your code uses it like an element. And that fails. Might want to look at the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) as they do it without any JavaScript.  And if you want to switch via a button, changing the href doesn't seem the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some more research.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line `var el = document.querySelectorAll("#light, #dark")`
should be `var el = document.querySelectorAll(".light, .dark")`, because your link tags have a class, not an id.

Another thing, in your second script tag, you try to update `el.href`, but in this function, `el` is never defined. It has been defined in another function (`lightDark()`), so it is not accessible anymore at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks, I've made these adjustments however I am still not getting the stylesheets to update. The icon swaps out however.

Comment: Can you check Yogi's comment on your question? And update your question with the updated code, we're going to fix it!

Comment: Thanks, the code has been updated.